# run tomcatRun task with debug mode

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, gradle

I've got multiple project which are using tomcat on different ports.
I usually run `tomcatRun` task simply using `gradle tR`.

But I need to debug one application - it runs on `localhost:9080` port so I created debug configuration in `eclipse` to use `localhost` and `9000` port.

But how to run `tomcatRun` task with debug properties? As a solution I found to use some variable

```
GRADLE_OPTS="-Xmx2048m -Xms2048m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

However I don't get how to set it for my current application - because I've got multiple application which are using tomcat and I want to run only one application in debug mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setenv.bat/setenv.sh in tomcat/bin directory and write

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m ...
```

Comment: But I need it only for one project. If set like this - every project that uses tomcat will run with this properties, am I wrong?

Comment: nope. But I have many project which runs on different ports - `application-rest`, `application-processor` and etc. And I need to run them simultaneously

Comment: if i understood you correctly and you have one tomcat instance that runs all your applications, you do not have an option to run only one application in debug mode.

when i run tomcat in a debug mode, all my applications are available for debugging

Comment: Well I added `setenv.bat` but it still changed nothing...I've created `setenv.bat` and wrote there only one line `set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9000,server=y,suspend=n`. I am trying to connect to applcation via `eclipse` and configuration `localhost:9000`. But still nothing.

Comment: How do you start your tomcat? I guess you use Eclipse for it.

Comment: Yes. I do. BTW the problem is resolved. I had some problem `under the hood` LoL